# how to get height if inner li element?

Tags: javascript

Below is the structure of my code:

```
<div class="commentDynamicDiv" id="commentDynamicDiv" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 147px;">
<li class="head-comment clearfix" id="link0" style="list-style: none;"></li>
<li class="head-comment clearfix" id="link1" style="list-style: none;"></li>
</div>
```

The `<div>` is added dynamically like this:

```
        _attrs = {
            id:'commentDynamicDiv',
            className:'commentDynamicDiv'
                 };

    var _commentDynamicDiv = createHTMLElement("div", div, _attrs);
    _commentDynamicDiv.style.overflowY= 'auto';
```

I want to be able to access the height of first `<li>` element of `<div>`. For this I have tried

```
_commentDynamicDiv.childNodes[0].style.height;
```

Is this the correct way to find the height value? Please provide some suggestions or tips on how I can find this.

Comment: `<li>` should have an `<ul>` or `<ol>` as a parent.

Comment: You need to have the height defined in order to access it with `.style.height`

Comment: thanks Fogolicious.i forgot to defined height